# Does there exist a non-trivial group variety other than the variety of all groups that is preserved by Levi operator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, universal-algebra, finitely-generated

Suppose $\mathfrak{U}$ is a group variety. Now let’s define $L(\mathfrak{U})$ as the class of all such groups $G$, such that $\forall g \in G$ $\langle \langle g \rangle \rangle \in \mathfrak{U}$ (here $\langle \langle ... \rangle \rangle$ stands for normal closure).  It is not hard to see, that $L(\mathfrak{U})$ is closed under subgroups, quotients and direct products, and thus is a variety too. So $L$ is an operator on group varieties. If I am not mistaken, it is usually called Levi operator.

It is always true, that $\mathfrak{U} \subset L(\mathfrak{U})$, however the converse is not true in general: for example, Levi operator maps the variety of abelian groups to the variety of $2$-Engel groups. The variety of all groups and the trivial variety are nevertheless preserved by it.

My question is:

> Do there exist such varieties $\mathfrak{U}$, such that $L(\mathfrak{U})=\mathfrak{U}$, but $\exists G \notin \mathfrak{U}$ and $\exists H \in \mathfrak{U}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the variety of groups of a given exponent $e > 1$?

Comment: Yes it is. If $\langle \langle g \rangle \rangle$ belongs to Burnside variety of exponent $n$ for all $g \in G$, then $g^n = e$ for all $g \in G$ and so $G$ belongs to the Burnside variety of exponent $n$ too. I wonder how did I miss something so obvious.